# JQuery $.post, PHP returns blank POST variables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post, .post

I cannot seem to get this to work. I have been researching this all day on Stack overflow and on the JQuery doc website itself, and no matter what i do, i cannot seem to get this to work.

Here is the HTML form (and the javascript for the JQuery post function):

```
<script>
function checkForm(){
// variable to hold request
var request;
// bind to the submit event of our form
$("#rchar").submit(function(event){
    // abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);
    // let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    // serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
    url: 'postregister.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: serializedData,
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('error');
    }   
});

    // callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    $("#navigation").html(serializedData);
    });

    // callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
});
}
</script>
<form id="rchar" method="POST" action="postrenamecharacter.php">
<h3>Test Form!</h3>
<table id="leftalignment1">
<tbody>
<tr><td>Name: </td><td><input type="text" size="35px" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" name="name"><input type="hidden" value="Test" id="hidden" name="hidden"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" size="35px" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password"></td><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table><br><br>
<input action="submit" value="  Register  " id="submit" type="submit"><br>
</form>
```

So the response will be posted in the Java terminal and the JQuery POST variables will be loaded into the navigation bar. The navigation bar has the correct variables by reading this:

`"name=Jeremy&hidden=Test&password=thisisatest"`

Here is the PHP function called "postregister.php"

```
<?php
$oldname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['hidden']);
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$title = "Your password is: ";
echo $title . "<br>" . $password . "<br>Your old name was: <br>" . $oldname;
?>
```

The issue is that the PHP code only returns this:

```
"Your password is: <br><br>Your old name was: <br>"
```

So obviously, the PHP variables are not being passed on to the PHP POST form from JQuery. Any help guys? I would really, REALLY appreciate it!

Thanks ^_^

Comment: What's the output of `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: @AmalMurali Array ( )

Comment: Is `$mysqli` connection made in your file?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Yes, i just removed that from the file for display.

Comment: @user2635579 you are calling `postrenamecharacter.php` using ajax and showing code of `postregister.php`. Is it typo?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Sorry, that was a publishing typo. They're the same in the actual code. I'll fix that now.

Comment: @user2635579 While doing ajax call is your page reloads? I am sure that it is because your form is explicitly posting. You need to disable the default posting after that it will work.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar No the page doesn't reload. So what exactly should i do? Just remove action, and method from the form yes?

Comment: Why do you have a wrapping function `function checkForm(){}` around `$("#rchar").submit(function(event){}`? Try removing it, as I think it might be preventing the binding/ajax from working, since you never call `checkForm()`.

Comment: @Sean I don't think that would be it. The JavaScript is still displaying the correct information, it's just not posting it for some reason.

Comment: @user2635579 I also, see no reference to your `checkForm()` function. Have you tried `<input action="submit" value="  Register  " id="submit" type="submit" onclick="return checkForm();">` or used it in your `<form`? You might have to get rid of the `return`. `onsubmit="return checkForm(this)"` **or** `onsubmit="return checkForm()"` **Try any one of those**.

Comment: @Fred I tried this and i still get the same result sadly :c

Comment: @user2635579 Darn it, I was pretty sure that's what it had to be. However, my take on it is, that you still have to figure a way to fire up that function. It's not being called, am pretty sure of that.

Comment: @user2635579 and you've tried this right? `<form id="rchar" method="POST" action="postrenamecharacter.php" onsubmit="return checkForm()">`

Comment: @user2635579 However since it is Ajax and you do have two `postrenamecharacter.php` set for for your POST action, you shouldn't need to have it in your `<form` Try removing it as such `<form id="rchar" method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return checkForm()">`

Comment: It's still not working. I don't understand what's wrong. The JavaScript Console keeps saying that there are no errors and everything is working, JQuery is getting the correct variables, yet PHP is not recieving them :\

Comment: @user2635579 Just for argument's sake, I'll ask a potentially very stupid question, yet this HAS happened before. **"Is JQuery JS loaded?"** I have seen a few cases where an OP did not have JQuery loaded. I'm not questioning your abilities here, yet I had to ask.

Comment: @user2635579 Underneath your `function checkForm(){` try adding this to it `data = $('rchar').serialize();`

Comment: @Fred Yes, JQuery is loaded, and don't worry, i'm not offended lol. 

And i already have serialize in there though? There is a variable named serializedData in my source code above. What should i do with that?

Comment: @user2635579 To tell you the truth, I'm not entirely sure. I started studying Ajax for a month or so now (Yet no stranger to PHP/CGI/etc.), and in studying the manual on the jQuery.com site, was trying to piece together how the serializing worked. Now we know for sure that your `checkForm()` is not being fire, that I know, because there is no linked reference to it. You have to figure out how to "fire it up", as it were, then the process should (theoretically) take care of itself.

Comment: I'm confused. The checkForm() function is working, everything that is supposed to happen, happens. The only thing that isn't working is the $.post part of the function.

Comment: @user2635579 `$.post`? I didn't see that in your code or `.post` only `type: "POST",`

Comment: @user2635579 Why don't you try `$.post("postregister.php");` instead of `url: 'postregister.php',`

Comment: did u var_dump($_POST) or echo "$_POST" and see? Please look at that, maybe the data is sent in a json format. I am guessing it.

Comment: @Fred i've already tried $.post instead, i get the same response.

Comment: @madi I did echo "$_POST" it just says "Array"

Comment: @user2635579 Try doing a `var_dump($oldname)` and `var_dump($password)` then post your results.

Comment: @Fred It returned an internal 500 error.

Comment: @user2635579 Did you happen to leave out the semi-colons at the end of them? I know I didn't post them, but try it again with `var_dump($oldname);` and `var_dump($password);`

Comment: @Fred Oops, yes i did. I added the semicolon and now the var_dump() comes out as NULL.

Comment: @user2635579 Seems like something's not going though or not assigned. Just as a quick test, try running this `$title = "Your password is: " . $password;`

Comment: @Fred Okay, nothing has changed in the output.

Comment: @user2635579 It has to be something in your DB then. I don't know what else to say.

Comment: @Fred I'm not using a DataBase anymore in my PHP code. I'm just using one that displays the POST variables. Even with my DB code, grabbing the data from the database worked, just grabbing the data from the page and sending it didn't.

Comment: @user2635579 Ok, let me see what I can do and copy your entire code as well as Madi's, see what my results are.

Comment: @user2635579 Hold on. I thought Madi's codes checked out. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Fred I am now using madi's code posted below. Same result. Nothing.

Comment: @user2635579 Ok man, I'll have to get to this later. My 'ol lady is getting on my case to get off the 'puter. I'll see what I can do for you later. Sorry bro

Comment: @Fred It's all good, thanks for trying. If you can find anything out sometime soon, tell me plz :x

Comment: @user2635579 I tested `Madi's` code and everything checked out on my end. What's it not doing for you? I got this result back in my source `Your password is: <br>123<br>Your old name was: <br>HIDDEN_VALUE` I replaced the word `hidden` with `HIDDEN_VALUE` in my test file.

Answer (score 0):

You did not even call the function **checkForm()** method so I am not sure how your code works but I used **$(document).ready(function()**

The following is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rchar").submit(function(event){
        alert("hahahaha");
        var request;
        // abort any pending request
        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }
        // setup some local variables
        var $form = $(this);
        // let's select and cache all the fields
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        // serialize the data in the form
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        // fire off the request to /form.php
        request = $.ajax({
        url: 'postregister.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: serializedData,
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error');
        }   
    });

        // callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $("#navigation").html(serializedData);
        });

        // callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // log the error to the console
            console.error(
                "The following error occured: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // prevent default posting of form
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The following is the html:

```
 <body>
    <form id="rchar" method="POST" action="postregister.php">
    <h3>Test Form!</h3>
    <table id="leftalignment1">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>Name: </td><td><input type="text" size="35px" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" name="name"><input type="hidden" value="Test" id="hidden" name="hidden"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" size="35px" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password"></td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table><br><br>
    <input action="submit" value="  Register  " id="submit" type="submit"><br>
    </form>
</body>
```

The following is the php script:

```
<?php
  $oldname = $_POST['hidden'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $title = "Your password is: ";
  echo $title . "<br>" . $password . "<br>Your old name was: <br>" . $oldname;
?>
```

I tested it and I am able to get the value from ajax to the php page

Comment: The php code is not included with $mysqli->real_escape_string() function.Please modify it yourself

Comment: I tried this, but i got this response...

"Your password is: 

Your old name was: "

Comment: @user2635579 If `madi` tested this code and was working, then my guess is that it has something to do with your DB and not your code.

Comment: @user2635579: Your concern was more on the post response and I have edited the code the way u wanted. The problem maybe with your sql. You should try without the mysqli first.